# AWS CPU usage issue when switching instance typs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I switched from a t2.micro instance to a m3.medium instance and I find that the CPU is much slower for the m3.medium.

The m3 instance gets hits 100% at tasks that were handled easily by the t2. The m3 instance also doesn't go above 100% in CPU usage unlike the t2.

I'm running Elasticsearch on an instance and for the t2 I used to get sub-50ms responses and now with the m3, it's at ~500ms. Any other task that I run is also slow, so it's not just related to ES. I've increase the memory for ES as well.

Not sure what's going on. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you switch from general purpose SSD to magnetic by any chance?

Comment: ..or your [memory configuration](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_limiting_memory_usage.html). Yay java thrashing.

Comment: T2 instances have a unique cpu profile: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html The issue could also be related to memory or IO.

Comment: I understood that it was variable, but not "the capability to burst to significantly higher performance as required by your workload". The word significant seems to be the key word here.

Comment: It looks like a micro instance had a 10% baseline CPU usage limit but could burst to one full core based on credits. m3.medium should have a full core all the time. I suspect the issue is memory or IO related. Did anything else change about your workload or configuration in addition to changing instance sizes?

Comment: Wait, a t2.micro going *above* 100% CPU?  It's only a 1-core machine (spot checking one of mine, it's an Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz Stepping 4) so going over over 100% CPU doesn't make sense for a t2.micro.  A t2.medium, on the other hand, has two such cores, and under intermittent load would be arguably twice the machine as an m3.medium and one process could hit close to 200% CPU.  Is it possible you had a t2.medium, not a micro?

Comment: I'm sure I had a micro as I was using it under the free tier, and I was keeping track of cpu usage for one of my apps.